# What would count as a counterexample to the Final-Over-Final Constraint?

Tags: syntax

I'm interested in what the constraints are on head-directionality and, in particular, which combinations of features are *disfavored*, *unstable*, or *thought to be impossible*.

I came across the final-over-final constraint (FOFC) a while back and am trying to figure out "where" it applies.

I'm going to start out with an *intentionally naive* statement of the FOFC (henceforth ultra-naive FOFC) and show that it doesn't hold by presenting a single counterexample.

So, in short, my question is:

- **Under what circumstances does FOFC apply?**
- **Is FOFC supposed to be an absolute rule or are FOFC-incompatible forms merely predicted to be diachronically unstable?**
- **What would constitute a *bona fide* counterexample to FOFC, one strong enough to suggest that theory is incorrect?**

The *ultra-naive FOFC* is the hypothesis that no FOFC violation occurs at any level in any phrase in any language.

---

The following English sentence is compatible with the ultra-naive FOFC

```
I see red cars
```

I'm not sure whether the subject or verb is considered the head of a clause, so I'll look at just the VP and mark heads like this: `^HEAD`.

```
^see [red ^cars]
```

Alternatively, let `[...]` denote a head-initial phrase and `(...)` a head-final one.

```
[see (red cars)]
```

However, there are prepositional SOV languages out there. Here's an example sentence from [Amharic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amharic#Grammar).

```
  እሱ   ወደ   ከተማ   መጣ
Ǝssu wädä kätäma mäṭṭa
  he   to   city  came
```

Amharic is pro-drop, so presumably the following sentence is also valid.

```
  ወደ   ከተማ   መጣ
wädä kätäma mäṭṭa
  to   city  came
```

The sentence presumably branches like this, with the verb as the head and the adpositional phrase as a dependent

```
[[^to city] ^came]
([to city] came)
```

So, the ultra-naive FOFC makes a bad prediction in this case.

However, if the real FOFC applies only to *single phrases at a time* then it never actually restricts anything.

So, which kinds of "subtrees" constitute domains in which the FOFC applies?

---

In order to learn more about FOFC, I read [this paper/handout/document](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.492.6099&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I am not sure how that document is intended to be used, it looks like it is instructional material for a class or material for a conference.

The handout actually mentions the case of prepositional SOV languages, and mentions Tigre, an Ethiopian Semitic language related to Amharic.

> Cross-linguistically, adpositions are strong verb patterners (Dryer
> 1992 i.a.), suggesting that they are [+V]. We therefore predict that
> PPs embedded under v should respect FOFC. There are a few notable
> exceptions to this, e.g. West Germanic, Iranian, Sorbian and Tigré
> (cf. Sheehan 2008a). This suggests that adpositions in these languages
> might not be [+V], or rather PPs might have a more complex structure.
> More generally, adpositions might not form a homogeneous class.

Comment: [This book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/final-over-final-condition) (which I haven't read) apparently argues that "FOFC is a linguistic universal, not just a strong tendency, and not a constraint on processing."

Comment: @ColinFine, I haven't read the book either, but I think the question `what would falsify this` is reasonable. The argument in favor of FOFC might be similar to `treating this as a foundational assumption and hypothesizing X when apparent violations occur leads to a parsimonious theory overall`. [This answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1009) mentions that it's possible to consider a different-but-similar idea, the existence of a head-directionality parameter, part of your framework rather than a testable hypothesis. The answer doesn't endorse that idea though.